# The use of the words "and" and "well" at the end of a sentence that is a list - conversational inclusion of the word "well"

Tags: commas, lists

I'll start with the sentence at hand; it's a doozy!

> *"I think Sherry cultivates a totally different/unique type of account person and mentality on her team: customer service is far and away #1, plus knowledge of course, coupled with what seems to be an unusual ability for the handful of us to circumvent some of the organization’s standard processes—likely due to the crazy tenure many of us have, the independence the SJ team is able to enjoy, **and, well,** largely due to Sherry herself."*

My primary question is particularly focused on the very end of the sentence which I have bolded: do I need to and/or is it an appropriate preference of mine to use successive series of commas after after "and" & "well"? Particularly, given that there is already a comma used after "enjoy," it seems excessive but I feel it very well may be correct(?).

Also, while I nerd out on grammar, I wonder if I am incorrect to use a slash at the beginning of the sentence "different/unique."

Lastly, should anyone reply, I'd welcome any other feedback you may have regarding any content found in my quoted sentence. Heck, even in the grammar I've used in the entirety of my posted question!

Comment: Yes, around the word well, but not necessarily after enjoy. Slashes are fine if that is what you want in your employee review. But you don't need it: Sherry cultivates a totally different, unique type of account person [whatever that is]. Floating adverbs take commas especially when they mimic spoken language, which this does. It functions like an spoken interjection.

Comment: The "unusual ability" is "likely due to" the three phrases that follow, but the third phrase starts with "largely due." So the sense of the third phrase is "likely due to largely due," which resists interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

[...]likely due to the crazy tenure many of us have, the independence the SJ team is able to enjoy, and, well, largely due to Sherry herself."

There are three separate phrases. It is not necessary to put a comma after enjoy: 
[...]likely due to the crazy tenure many of us have, the independence the SJ team is able to enjoy and, well, largely due to Sherry herself."

If you do use it, it's called an Oxford comma: three separate things with a comma between the second and third element (phrase, clause, word).

Compare: John, Mary and Sarah ****versus**** John, Mary, and Sarah.

Both are correct.

Well is inserted as an interjection, and therefore would take commas around it to set it off as such. I would suggest using "in fact" instead of "well".

Since you do have **well**, I would suggest removing the comma after enjoy so the text does not seem so comma-full.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough and quick response! And for context, the sentence at hand was merely part of a short and informal email I was composing in response to a client. The import of the grammar was purely my own unexplained curiosity and unbashed enthusiasm for grammar. Many thanks.